# Import a project to STS iMac

Tags: java, spring

I recently purchased an iMac and installed Springsource Tool Suite. I am currently trying to import a project. If I import the project as 'an existing Java project', all the files import but I have build path errors and a couple of other errors that I have not been able to resolve. I also tried creating a new java project and importing the file system of the project I want to import, saying no to all when prompted with the Overwrite '.classpath' message. The result of this is nothing gets imported. I tried saying 'yes to all' and the result is the same. I am relatively new to java. Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have JDK installed and configured in STS? What errors you got?

Comment: Details! We need more details!

Comment: If the project is using maven, you can run `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` to regenerate the eclipse shims. Then you need only define a new project with the correct path and everything should be fine.

Comment: If I import as an existing project, I get the following errors: I get a build path error next to the package name and the import java.util.ArrayList and import java.util.List statements are not recognized. If I try to import the file system, there are no errors that I can see but no files are imported. I see the original src and JRE System Library folders when I created the new java project. On my PC, I can import as an existing project with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

For most spring projects you should import them as a maven project.

File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven projects