# Spring STS errors on spring-mvc-showcase (and others)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-tool-suite

I have installed STS 3.61 on OSx Maveicks with Java 1.8.0_11 and Tomcat 8.0.12. I have started a project with (Right-click)->New->Import Spring Getting Started Content->spring-mvc-showcase; Right-click on spring-mvc-showcase->Debug->Debug On Server. I get an internal browser window with the URL java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.samples.mvc.data.custom.CustomArgumentResolver]. The URL displays a Status 500 window with the root cause "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.samples.mvc.data.custom.CustomArgumentResolver]". There was some good data in [Import a project to STS iMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822212) on this problem.

Let me give a bit of history. I did this earlier and everything worked great. I played with upgrading some artifact versions and got this error along the way. I did some of the things in [Import a project to STS iMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822212) and it seemed to resolve the problem. After a few more changes, however, I got to the point that nothing would get rid of the error. I even tried the following sequence: remove project from Tomcat, clean Tomcat, clean project, delete project, shutdown STS, restart STS, recreate project. It still didn't work.

Any suggestions before I reinstall STS and Tomcat? I really don't like this solution as it really hampers development in the long run.

Comment: does this problem appear for the spring-mvc-showcase project only? And can you maybe provide exact steps for how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm trying with a different sample as a base now and I haven't seen the problem (yet).

Comment: ok, that sounds good. let me know if you come across this issue again.